# Java loop based on user input

Tags: java, loops, jgrasp

I have this program that generates a random number that you have to guess. If it's too high or too low, it tells you. I need to to ask after every guess whether or not you want to continue. I've tried using a nested if statement and keep getting all sorts of errors. I'm using jgrasp to code this. I'm new to coding by the way.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class redo
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
    //Generate a random number and set values
    Random r = new Random();
    int number = r.nextInt(100);
    System.out.println(number); 
    boolean win = false;

    //Loop    
    while (win == false)
    {

    //Input guess
    System.out.println("Please guess a number 1-100:");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int guess = scan.nextInt();

    //Compare input with correct answer
    if  (guess == number)
      { 
         System.out.println("You are correct! the number was " + number + "!");
         win = true;
   } 
      else if (guess > number)
      {
         System.out.println("That number is too high.");
      }
      else if (guess < number)
      {
         System.out.println("That number is too low.");
      } 

  }
  } 
}
```

EDITED

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class redo
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
//Generate a random number and set values
Random r = new Random();
int number = r.nextInt(100);
System.out.println(number); 
   boolean win = false;

   //Loop
   while (win == false)
   {

//Input guess
System.out.println("Please guess a number 1-100:");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int guess = scan.nextInt();

//Compare input with correct answer
  if  (guess == number)
  { 
     System.out.println("You are correct! the number was " + number + "!");
     win = true;
   } 
  else if (guess > number)
  {
     System.out.println("That number is too high.");
  }
  else if (guess < number)
  {
     System.out.println("That number is too low.");
  } 

   System.out.println("Would you like to guess again? Please enter Y or N: ");
   String yesorno = scan.next();
   char nooryes = yesorno.charAt(0);
   char No = 'N';
   char no = 'n';
   char Yes = 'Y';
   char yes = 'y';

   while (win == true)

   if (nooryes == No || nooryes == no)
  {
  win = true;
  }
   else if (nooryes == Yes || nooryes == yes)
  {
  win = false;
  }
   else
  {
  System.out.println("I can't read that. Please enter Y or N: ");
  }


      }
   }    
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: " I need to to ask after every guess whether or not you want to continue."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a new boolean in while loop check.

```
while (win == false && shouldContinue == true)
```

And ask the question after,

```
if  (guess == number)
      { 
         System.out.println("You are correct! the number was " + number + "!");
         win = true;
   } 
      else if (guess > number)
      {
         System.out.println("That number is too high.");
      }
      else if (guess < number)
      {
         System.out.println("That number is too low.");
      }
```

By the way, please include your code which gave error, if this does not work.

Comment: So I added something and I probably went the long way around but it works for the most part. The only two problems it has now are if you guess the correct number, it still asks if you want to guess again. The other is if you input anything other than y or n, it goes on an endless loop.

Comment: Ok, then before asking the question add `if(guess == number)`
And, about the endless loop I would use `if(x == 'y'){shouldContinue = true;} else {shouldContinue = false;}`